# Run tmux not byobu

Tags: byobu, tmux

I've been using tmux for a number of years, earlier today I thought I'd try byobu - to see what it's like. But now I can't get back to tmux. When I run tmux I end up back in boyobu. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: By removing Byobu?

Answer (score 3):

You need to kill the original `tmux` server, that was started by the `byobu` process.

You can do this using:

```
tmux kill-server
```

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [byobu](http://byobu.co).*